# Lambda function cannot connect to RDS instance on same subnet and in same security gorup

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda

I have a lambda function and a RDS instance on AWS.
I have tried the following to get it to connect:

Put them both in the same VPC, same security group(s) and the same subnet.  When I try to connect to the RDS instance (MariaDB) from the lambda function I am getting a `Error: connect ETIMEDOUT`.
I have also given the Lambda function a role which has full EC2, RDS, VPC and Lambda rights.

However if I allow all traffic into the RDS instance Security Group (bad, I know!) and remove the Lambda function from the VPC then it can connect (verifying that the credentials etc. are correct)

EDIT:
I have made changes based on your comments and included extra information about the role and security group set up.  Please see below screen shots.
Config screen shots below:

The Lambda function VPC Settings:

[image]

The RDS instance VPC Settings:

[image]

The security group inbound settings:

[image]

The lambda function role:

[image]

Comment: Can you show the code please?

Comment: Is the security group permitted to talk to itself?

Comment: I have added extra information

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured the roles as explained in this URL?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc-rds-create-iam-role.html

Try adding "--vpc-config SubnetIds=comma-separated-vpc-subnet-ids,SecurityGroupIds=comma-separated-security-group-ids \" to the lambda function as explained in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc.html.

Also, RDS is public. Do you need this by design?

Comment: I have included a screen shot of the roles (etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue while using `mysql` npm package. In the process of debugging I've tried to see what ip address does the hostname resolve to with:

```
const { lookup: lc } = require('dns');
const { promisify } = require('util');

const lookup = promisify(lc);
const { address } = await lookup('<my-hostname.com>');
```

Then I've checked that IP address was in the range specified for the RDS instance and subnets and it matched availability zone.

Problem is that `mysql` was trying to resolve the hostname from public DNS probably. So rather than passing the hostname I've just passed the resolved IP address into the initialization of mysql and it worked.